# LogIn Page Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Before 3 days the code was working fine. But now its not.
please point out my mistake as i am new to JQuery.

I debugged it, and found out that debugger is not entering inside success method of ajax. and not even going to CS file.

Code of Jquery-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            alert('b');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "admin.aspx/LogIn",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{'name':'" + $('#txtfn').val() + "','password':'"     +$('#txtln').val() + "'}",
                success: function (data) {

                    alert(data);
                    var obj = data.d;
                    alert(obj);
                    alert(data.d);
                    if (obj == 'true') {
                        $('#txtfn').val('');
                        $('#txtln').val('');
                        alert("dasdsad");
                        window.location = "home.aspx";
                        alert("success");
                    }
                    else if (obj == 'false')
                    { alert("errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr"); }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(data);
                    alert("aaaaaaafgdgfdfgsfgfhffghgfhgfhfghfghfhfghfhfghgfhgfhgfhgfhfghfghgfhgfhgf");
                    alert(result);
                }
            });

           });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
&nbsp;<div id="login">
    <div id="triangle"></div>
    <h1>Log in</h1>
    <form id="f1" runat="server">

        <input type="text" id="txtfn" placeholder="name" />
        <input type="text" id="txtln" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Log in" />
    </form>
   </div>
</body>
```

Code-

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LogIn(string name, string password)
{
    string retMessage = string.Empty;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["oltest_conString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string Query = "select * from profile where name=@pname and password=@pwd";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", password);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                //retMessage = "home.aspx";
                retMessage = "true";
            }

            else
            {
                retMessage = "false";
            }
        }
        return retMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: use Firefox Firegbug console

Comment: I already used it...still not able to find out error. I am new to JQuery

Comment: Do you have captured the request? You can use network tab in Firefox or Chrome. Do you run the request?

Comment: i dont know how to do it. I am using FireFox

Comment: Alter this - `$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {` to `$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {` and then modify your code like this: `$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();`. Just a guess but worth trying. The using of `form` here is very suspicious in my opinion.

Comment: I tried...still not working

Comment: except alert('b'); . nothing is executing. i checked in FireBug

Comment: You are using `data` in your `error: function`, which is not defined, hence the entire `$.ajax` won't evaluate.

Comment: thanks...now error function is called

Comment: Can you please tell me why its not going into .aspx.cs file?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove

```
alert('b');``
```

on your jquery code

Comment: sorry, it was typed by mistake when i was pasting my question here.

Comment: its ok, I upvote this question a while ago so others can help. hope you'll fix this :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi change your submit button to button.

```
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Log in" />


 data: {name: $('#txtfn').val() ,password: $('#txtln').val()},
```

Comment: yeah...actually i put alert inside success method , its not executing.

Comment: data: {name: $('#txtfn').val() ,password: $('#txtln').val()},

Comment: ^ Are you sure? Because i always use with Inverted Commas

Comment: You just try it. and remove the form form the html.

Answer (score 0):

**I updated my answer:**
your ajax call is not executed because form is submitted, this code will prevent submission

```
$("#f1").submit(function (e) {e.preventDefault();})
```

place it before `$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {`


**better way will be place your code inside**

```
$("#f1").submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // here place content of $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {( )}
})
```

Comment: yeah it executes...alert box of 'b' pop ups

Comment: does xhr request was send to server and what was the status code and response from the server? does the 'alert(data);' executed?

Comment: except 'b' . nothing is executing. i checked in FireBug

Comment: your form is submitting... what happens after you made changes accroding to comment of Leron? on my machine now xhr request is done

Comment: try to add  $("#f1").submit(function (e) {e.preventDefault();})  currently form is submited (submit event fires) before ajax post is executed, stop it and we will se result of ajax. I tested it on my loaclhost machine, ajax is executed.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a

```
return false
```

at the end of the ajax call

Comment: @user2096592 Your dataType is set to json, try dataType 'text', as defined by jQuery any malformed json is rejected.

Comment: is your request sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure JSON data /parameters accepted by your web method and it returning proper true/false without any exception/error.
You can do it by debugging in firebug and Visual Studio.